# spark-shell, pyspark are not working properly

Tags: apache-spark

I've installed spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7 on Ubuntu and I don’t think it has some problem with the java path. When I run "spark-submit --version" or "spark-shell" or "pyspark" I get the following error:

`/usr/local/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd-64/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory`

It seems "/bin/java" is problematic, but I'm not sure where to change the configuration. The spark-class file has the following lines:

`if [ -n "${JAVA_HOME}" ]; then
  RUNNER="${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java`

The /etc/environment is:

`bash: /etc/environment: Permission denied`

What I now have in gedit ~/.bashrc is:

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd-64/jre`

`export PATH=$PATH:JAVA_HOME/bin`

This is the current java setup that I have:

`root@ubuntu:~# update-alternatives --config java There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Nothing to configure.`

bashrc has the following:

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/scala-2.11.8/bin`

`export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7`

`export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin`

Suggest me:

1. What files I need to change and
2. how I need to change them?

Comment: did you set the JAVA_HOME in your `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh` file?

Comment: see the docs :smiley: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#environment-variables

Answer (score 1):

#### Java Home

Your JAVA_HOME should be set to your JDK
`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd-64/jre`
should be
`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd-64`

Here is the Oracle doc on `JAVA_HOME` (which should apply to Open JDK as well) 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/

#### Spark Environmental Variables

The `JAVA_HOME` should also be set in the `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh`
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#environment-variables

Comment: no, i didn't set  JAVA_HOME in  $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh file. but when i write  JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd-64
  in spark-env.sh file  it is not able to save it and it Could not find the file “/conf/spark-env.sh”. But set JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd-64 in /etc/environment is working for me , but still not able to run sparkR i tried to run ./bin/sparkR and the error i got is :env: ‘R’: No such file or directory

Comment: **Spark Environmental Variables** document is usful